Error making a transaction "payment"
I created a transaction "Payment" but can't execute. The error I get is
"result":
{
2 items
"error":
"Transaction contains unsupported operation type: OperationTypePayment",
"latestLedger":
0,
Anybody can help guide on how to navigate this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
